# jQuery smooth scroll disables class change on window location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I'm working on a project which has two jQuery scripts.

The first is a plug in for smooth scrolling - [Ariel Flesler Smooth Scroll](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo).

The second is a jQuery script that changes the class of a fixed top navigation bar when it goes to 1085px.

The problem is that when you click the anchor to scroll down the page to the next section, the jQuery doesn't fire and the top bar's class doesn't change. When you scroll with a mouse or move the scroll bar, the script fires and the class is changed. I searched all over with no answers. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the top-bar script:

```
$(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    var header = $(".head-bar");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 1085) {
            header.removeClass('trans-bar').addClass("dark-bar");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("dark-bar").addClass('trans-bar');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've actually figured this out, I just needed to increase the window location number and it fixed it.